# How to change the default admin password in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: admin, password-encryption, activemq-artemis

I've checked the docs, but so far haven't found how to change the default admin password in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.27.1 created when using the `artemis create` command.

Here are the contents of the `etc/login.config`:

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};
```

These are the contents of `artemis-users.properties`:

```
admin = ENC(1024:EE12ADBFA02C8DB4AF73E22F44C9BD2C12861A2CD01186CA07A874FAA824A757:BA04C1C3F55B0F68EFB2804BB001EAC2C5105EC1662DCBF96E158F9DA3E0C1BB9D8ECA2FF77BBD391938BCB1E69D865322981AB134BF81B1378AFBBE9C040350)

#admin = ENC(1024:389da8e6db1d6dc50b300ec99ea5604a)
```

I tried masking the the password as described [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/masking-passwords.html), (this is the commented admin), but got invalid credentials  when I tried to login after restarting the server.

I generated it like this:

```
./artemis mask <plaintextPassword>
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. For example, are you referring to the username and password you supplied when creating the broker instance using the `artemis create` command? What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using? Can you paste the contents of your `etc/login.config`?

Comment: @JustinBertram -  I have answered your questions in the body of the message. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default credentials are stored in the `etc/artemis-users.properties`. Each line represents a user and its password in the format:

```
<user> = <password>
```

Passwords are hashed by default and stored using the `ENC()` syntax, but you can use plain text password if you want. Also, by default any changes to `artemis-users.properties` and `artemis-roles.properties` are reloaded automatically (since `reload=true` in `login.config`) so there's no need to restart the broker.

More details are available in [the documentation for the `PropertiesLoginModule`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#propertiesloginmodule).

If you want to update the file manually with a hashed password you need to use the following command in the `bin` directory:

```
$ ./artemis mask --hash <password>
```

This is documented in the ["Masking Passwords" chapter](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/masking-passwords.html).

Additionally, if you have at least one valid, working user account with the `manage` permission or if you have anonymous login enabled then you can use the `user` commands to list, add, remove, and reset users. As before, more details can be found [in the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/masking-passwords.html#artemis-usersproperties).